# How can I get a custom CIFilter to work on a CALayer for export using the AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, core-image, cifilter

When using a custom `CIFilter` that relies on custom input parameters the parameters are not used once you set the filter to the `CALayer` backgroundFilters so you can render it as a video using `AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool(postProcessingAsVideoLayer(s):)` the input parameters are no longer used, it looks like CALayer creates a new CIFilter and does not add the set parameters.

Using the default options:

```
let layer = CALayer()
let filter = CIFilter(name: "CustomFilter")!
filter.setValue(10, forKey: "value")
layer.backgroundFilters = [filter]
```

or:

```
let layer = CALayer()
let filter = CIFilter(name: "CustomFilter", options: ["value": 10])!
layer.backgroundFilters = [filter]
```

or using what Apple mentions in the manual:

```
let layer = CALayer()
let filter = CIFilter(name: "CustomFilter")!
filter.name = "myFilter"
layer.backgroundFilters = [filter]
layer.setValue(10, forKeyPath: "backgroundFilters.myFilter.value"
```

No matter what order, what values, if the custom filter is defined like this:

```
class CustomFilter: CIFilter {
    override class var supportsSecureCoding: Bool {
        return true
    }

    
    @objc dynamic var inputImage: CIImage?
    @objc dynamic var value: NSNumber?

    override public var outputImage: CIImage? {
        guard let image = inputImage else {
            return nil
        }

        // return the actual stuff you want done here!
    }
}
```

and even registered using:

```
class CustomFilterRegister: CIFilterConstructor {
    static func register() {
        CIFilter.registerName(
            "CustomFilter", constructor: CustomFilterRegister(),
            classAttributes: [
                kCIAttributeFilterCategories: [
                    kCICategoryVideo,
                    kCICategoryStillImage,
                    "CustomFilters"
                ],
            ])
    }
    
    func filter(withName name: String) -> CIFilter? {
        switch name {
        case "CustomFilter":
            return CustomFilter()
        default:
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

The CALayer is NOT affected by the setting in the value param.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seem to be 2 things that are important to add in order for `CALayers` to work with the custom `CIFilter`.

1. You need to override the inputKeys:

> ```
> override var inputKeys: [String] {
>    return [kCIInputImageKey, "value"]
> }
> ```

2. You need to declare all used parameters like this:

> ```
> override var attributes: [String : Any] {
>   return [
>       kCIAttributeFilterDisplayName: "Custom Filter",
>       kCIAttributeFilterName: "CustomFilter",
>       kCIAttributeFilterCategories: [
>           kCICategoryVideo,
>           kCICategoryStillImage,
>           "CustomFilters",
>       ],
>       kCIInputImageKey: [
>           kCIAttributeIdentity: 0,
>           kCIAttributeClass: "CIImage",
>           kCIAttributeDisplayName: "Image",
>           kCIAttributeType: kCIAttributeTypeImage
>       ],
>       #keyPath(value): [
>           kCIAttributeIdentity: 0,
>           kCIAttributeClass: "NSNumber",
>           kCIAttributeDisplayName: "Custom value",
>           kCIAttributeMin: 0,
>           kCIAttributeMax: 5,
>           kCIAttributeSliderMin: 0,
>           kCIAttributeSliderMax: 5,
>           kCIAttributeType: kCIAttributeTypeScalar
>       ],
>       kCIOutputImageKey: [
>           kCIAttributeClass: "CIImage",
>           kCIAttributeDisplayName: "Output Image",
>           kCIAttributeType: kCIAttributeTypeImage
>       ]
>   ]
> }
> ```

Hope I save some of you loads of time figuring this one out!

Comment: Oh, nice find! Does this also work for filters with custom Metal kernels?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but my guess is that it should. The problem seems to be the CALayer that somehow re-created the CIFilter and sets the values in a different way than the normal init. I would not see why not, but hey, didn't expect this to be there either ;)

Comment: Btw, you can also easily apply CIFilters to a video using `AVVideoComposition.init(asset:applyingCIFiltersWithHandler:)`. No need to use `CALayer` for that. 

Comment: True story, how ever we rely on a `AVVideoCompositing` class that combines videos and we need a second cut out layer that is affected by the `CIFilter` in our case with additional drawings on CALayers on top. And when you use AVVideoCompositing you can't use that callback as far as I'm aware.

Comment: Ah, true. You have to do it all by yourself in the custom compositor in this case.

Comment: yes, than we are expected to really know what we are doing ;)... If only we where....